# How can I make this not move and only load beneath it?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Currently, if you click item 2, it will reveal a input box and also widen the `<li>`. I don't want it to alter the size of the `<li>` and I want it to open right beneath item 2. How can i achieve this? Also, I want to make it close on click after it's been opened, but my jQuery doesn't seem to work.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#menu').click(
            function() {  $('fieldset', this).slideDown(); }, 
            function() {  $('fieldset', this).slideUp(); });
    });
</script>

<style>
ul, li {
    float: right;
    display: inline;
    margin: 0px
    padding: 0px

}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
    <li>item 1  </li>
    <li id="menu">Item 2 
    <fieldset style="display: none;">
        <form>
            <input type="text">
        </form>
    </fieldset>


    </li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

To hide the field, replace `click` in your code with `toggle`.

Answer (score 0):

This alteration should do the trick.

```
<li id="menu"> <div style="display:block">Item 2 </div>

    <fieldset id="field1" style="display: none;">
        <form>
            <input type="text">
        </form>
    </fieldset>


</li>
```

To close it the jquery command would be

```
$('#menu').click(function(){
    $('#field1').hide();
});
```

Comment: Wat about a <br /> tag in between?
Also try it with a <div> instead of <span>

Comment: The `<li>` is expanding because of the `<fieldset>`